# Socket Programming problem in java

Tags: java, sockets

i got this code from your site a while back.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class sevr implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket sSkt = null;
        Socket skt = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try{
            System.out.println("Server: is about to create socket");
            sSkt = new ServerSocket(6666);
            System.out.println("Server: socket created");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server: socket creation failure");
        }
        try{
            System.out.println("Server: is listening");
            skt = sSkt.accept();
            System.out.println("Server: Connection Established");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server: listening failed");
        }
        try{
            System.out.println("Server: creating streams");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream()));
            System.out.println("Server: stream done");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server: stream failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Server: reading the request");
        try{
            String line = null;
            line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server: client said-> "+ line);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server: reading failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Server: reading fished");

        System.out.println("Server: responding");
        try{
            bw.write("Hi! I am server!\n");
            bw.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server: responding failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Server: responding finished");

        System.out.println("Server: is finishing");
        try {
            br.close();
            bw.close();
            skt.close();
            sSkt.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Server: finishing failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Server: done");
    }
}

class clnt implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        Socket skt = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try{
            System.out.println("Client: about to create socket");
            skt = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),6666);
            System.out.println("Client: socket created");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Client: socket creation failure");
        }

        try{
            System.out.println("Client: creating streams");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream()));
            System.out.println("Client: stream done");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Client: stream failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Client: requesting");
        try{
            bw.write("Hi! I am Client!\n");
            bw.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Client: requesting failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Client: requesting finished");
        System.out.println("Client: reading the respond");
        try{
            String line = null;
            line =br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client: server said-> "+ line);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Client: reading failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Client: reading fished");



        System.out.println("Client: is finishing");
        try {
            br.close();
            bw.close();
            skt.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Client: finishing failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Client: done");
    }
}


public class Soc {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main started");
        Thread sThread = new Thread(new sevr());
        Thread cThread = new Thread(new clnt());
        sThread.start();
        cThread.start();
        try {
            sThread.join();
            cThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("joining failed");
        }
        System.out.println("Main done");

    }

}
```

I am connected to a network through a router. A total of 3 laptops are connected to the network. I ran this code on eclipse. The code executed successfully without returning any errors. But how do i know which laptop did my laptop create a connection with?? How do i determine this?

Comment: Looks like the laptop is connecting to itself, from the line `skt = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),6666);`

Comment: @Fareesh - Agreed. Also 2 threads named sThread and cThread are referring to a server and client thread.

Comment: Whenever you get an Exception, only catch it if you can do something useful.  Printing out a message and pretending nothing went wrong is not useful.

Comment: You should be able to see messages from the client and the server on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't have connected to any other computer.  The program is running both the client and server on the same machine.

```
skt = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),6666);
```

As you can see here the client is connecting to local host on port 6666.  And the server is listening for connections on port 6666.  To connect to another computer you would need to separate out the client and server code and run them on different machines.  You would then have to change the above line to create the socket to the address of the machine where the server is running.

Comment: I followed your instructions, separated out the codes and rewrote the code as you have told above. I am getting an error at the server side which says - 

Main started
Server: is about to create socket
Server: socket creation failure
Server: is listening
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sockettest.sevr.run(Soc.java:23)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Main done
Client side is stuck at the line "Client: reading the response"

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>        skt = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),6666);
> ```

You can turn off all your other computers :) you're connecting from localhost to localhost.

Once you modify your client code to connect to the server code running on another machine, you can use the [`getRemoteSocketAddress()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress%28%29) method to discover the `SocketAddress` of the remote peer.